# How to use select in Laravel to get related field value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following code:

```
return Visitor::with("checker")
               ->select(
                    'idVisitor', 
                    'firstname', 
                    'lastname', 
                    'middlename',
                    'birthday',             
                    'document_number', 
                    'pincode', 
                    'company', 
                    'idEvent',
                    'code',
                    'checker.name' 
                    'status'
                )
               ->whereIn("idVisitor", $this->ids)
               ->get();
```

As you can see I use related model: `with("checker")`.

How to get this field value in `select()`?

I tried: `'checker.name'`

Comment: Seems I should use leftJoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
Visitor::select('visitors.*', 'checker.name as checkerName')
    ->join('checkers', 'visitor.id', '=', 'checkers.idVisitor')
    ->whereIn('checkers.idVisitor', $this->ids)
    ->get();
```

The way you want it this should work, but i would recommend using eager loading using the with() method.

You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 3):

`with()` actually does multiple queries - it'll take the `Visitor` query's list of IDs and then do a subsequent query against the `checker` table with a `WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3...)` on it.

If you want to limit what the eager loading fetches (like `select()` does), you can do `with('checker:id,foo,bar')` to only select certain columns.

You'd access the relationship data the same old way - as a property on the resulting models. So, in your list of visitors, `$visitor->checker->name`.

(You can do this without the `with()` call, incidentally. `with()` just does eager loading, which will save you a bunch of queries if you're selecting *multiple* Visitor models.)

Comment: I want to get field name in `select`

Comment: @OPV That's not really how `with` or Laravel relationships work, though. Yes, you can do a `JOIN` using Laravel's functions, but it's not necessarily the right thing to do - it can add complexities/gotchas.

Comment: @OPV as @ceejayoz said, what you want to do is select a specific field (or set of fields) of the relationship.. that is exactly what you can do with the `with()` method. You could specify the columns there instead than in the select statement.